# What is wrong with this code ? I am extracting values form a predefined 2-dimensional array

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

struct Pokemon
{
      string type1, type2;
};

struct Trainer
{
    Pokemon poke1, poke2;
    int score;
};

class BPI
{
    Trainer red, blue;

public:

void DataAccept()
{

// Trainer RED

{

    // Pokemon 1

    cout<<"Please enter 3 letter type codes for 1st Pokemon of Red Trainer IN UPPERCASE :"<<endl;
    cin>>red.poke1.type1>>red.poke1.type2;

    // Pokemon 2

    cout<<"Please enter 3 letter type codes for 2nd Pokemon of Red Trainer IN UPPERCASE :"<<endl;
    cin>>red.poke2.type1>>red.poke2.type2;

}

cout<<endl;

// Trainer BLUE

{

    // Pokemon 1

    cout<<"Please enter 3 letter type codes for 1st Pokemon of Blue Trainer IN UPPERCASE :"<<endl;
    cin>>blue.poke1.type1>>blue.poke1.type2;

    // Pokemon 2

    cout<<"Please enter 3 letter type codes for 2nd Pokemon of Blue Trainer IN UPPERCASE :"<<endl;
    cin>>blue.poke2.type1>>blue.poke2.type2;

}
}

void process()
{
    int kci;

    int i;

    for (i = 1;i <17;i++)
    {
        string tk_red; string tk_blue;

        switch(i)
        {
            case(1):  {tk_red = red.poke1.type1; tk_blue = blue.poke1.type1;}
            case(2):  {tk_red = red.poke1.type1; tk_blue = blue.poke1.type2;}
            case(3):  {tk_red = red.poke1.type1; tk_blue = blue.poke2.type1;}
            case(4):  {tk_red = red.poke1.type1; tk_blue = blue.poke2.type2;}
            case(5):  {tk_red = red.poke1.type2; tk_blue = blue.poke1.type1;}
            case(6):  {tk_red = red.poke1.type2; tk_blue = blue.poke1.type2;}
            case(7):  {tk_red = red.poke1.type2; tk_blue = blue.poke2.type1;}
            case(8):  {tk_red = red.poke1.type2; tk_blue = blue.poke2.type2;}
            case(9):  {tk_red = red.poke2.type1; tk_blue = blue.poke1.type1;}
            case(10): {tk_red = red.poke2.type1; tk_blue = blue.poke1.type2;}
            case(11): {tk_red = red.poke2.type1; tk_blue = blue.poke2.type1;}
            case(12): {tk_red = red.poke2.type1; tk_blue = blue.poke2.type2;}
            case(13): {tk_red = red.poke2.type2; tk_blue = blue.poke1.type1;}
            case(14): {tk_red = red.poke2.type2; tk_blue = blue.poke1.type2;}
            case(15): {tk_red = red.poke2.type2; tk_blue = blue.poke2.type1;}
            case(16): {tk_red = red.poke2.type2; tk_blue = blue.poke2.type2;}
        }

    for (kci = 0; kci < 19; kci ++)
    {

            state(tk_red,tk_blue);

    }

    }

}

int code(string type)
{
        if (type == "NIL")
        {
            return 0;
        }

        else if (type == "NOR")
        {
            return 1;
        }

        else if (type == "FIR")
        {
            return 2;
        }

        else if (type == "WAT")
        {
            return 3;
        }

        else if (type == "GRA")
        {
            return 4;
        }

        else if (type == "ELE")
        {
            return 3;
        }

        else if (type == "PSY")
        {
            return 11;
        }

        else if (type == "GHO")
        {
            return 14;
        }

        else if (type == "DAR")
        {
            return 16;
        }

        else if (type == "FAI")
        {
            return 18;
        }

        else if (type == "ICE")
        {
            return 5;
        }

        else if (type == "DRA")
        {
            return 15;
        }

        else if (type == "GRO")
        {
            return 9;
        }

        else if (type == "ROC")
        {
            return 13;
        }

        else if (type == "STE")
        {
            return 17;
        }

        else if (type == "FLY")
        {
            return 10;
        }

        else if (type == "POI")
        {
            return 8;
        }

        else if (type == "FIG")
        {
            return 7;
        }

        else if (type == "BUG")
        {
            return 12;
        }
}

void state(string kred,string kblue)
{
    int typechart[20][20] =
    {
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-2,0,0,-1,0},
        {0,0,-1,-1,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,-1,0,-1,0,2,0},
        {0,0,2,-1,0,-1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,-1,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,2,-1,-1,0,0,0,-2,2,0,0,0,0,0,-2,0,0},
        {0,0,-1,2,0,-1,0,0,-1,2,-1,0,-1,2,0,-1,0,-1,0},
        {0,0,-1,-1,0,2,-1,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,-1,0},
        {0,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,-1,0,-1,-1,-1,2,-2,0,2,2,-1},
        {0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,-1,-1,0,0,0,-1,-1,0,0,-2,2},
        {0,0,2,0,2,-1,0,0,2,0,-2,0,-1,2,0,0,0,2,0},
        {0,0,0,0,-1,2,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,-1,0,0,0,-1,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,-2,-1,0},
        {0,0,-1,0,0,2,0,-1,-1,0,-1,2,0,0,-1,0,2,-1,-1},
        {0,0,2,0,0,0,2,-1,0,-1,2,0,2,0,0,0,0,-1,0},
        {0,-2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,-1,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,-1,-2},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,-1,0,-1},
        {0,0,-1,-1,-1,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,2,-1,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,-1,0}
    };

    red.score += typechart[code(kred)][code(kblue)];
    blue.score += typechart[code(kblue)][code(kred)];
}
};

int main()
{
    BPI ob;
    ob.DataAccept();
    ob.process();

    return 0;
}
```

This will accept 8 strings in 2 teams, them match them up, & modify the score accordingly, then it will print the score.

But it returns 0 for both trainers.

NOTE : I'm a pokemon freak, so I'm writing a program that compares the type advantages of the trainers.

Comment: Add `break` statements to your `switch`. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch

Comment: I don't think it's related to the specific problem you're having, but you never initialize `Trainer::score` anywhere, so the values of `ob.red.score` and `ob.blue.score` are indeterminate.

Comment: Also, `code()` needs to always return a value.

Comment: What do you mean by "But it returns 0 for both trainers?" Your code in ideone.com extended by `cout << red.score << endl << blue.score << endl;` prints numbers different from 0!?

Comment: A side note:  over half that code could be removed if you used a little ingenuity.  You are basically duplicating code in the `switch` giving you the issue.  Also, that endless `if` block detecting the type could be simplified by using a `map` or a simple lookup table, thus resulting in all that code being turned into a 2 or 3 line function.

Comment: And, sorry, this is not the full code. The print function was not copied properly. Also, there were more edits to this code. I think I posted an older version. Sorry, everyone

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I want to do so, but I don't know how

Comment: @everyone thank you for your help. You can find the full source code [here](https://github.com/pokemongva/appdev)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `break` statements.

```
     switch(i)
     {
        case(1):  {tk_red = red.poke1.type1; tk_blue = blue.poke1.type1;}
        case(2):  {tk_red = red.poke1.type1; tk_blue = blue.poke1.type2;}
        ...
```

`tk_red` and `tk_blue` will always have values as per `case(16)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are showing the score nowhere. try add at the end of the process method something like cout<

A little advice, avoid the usage of all those elseif, use insead a switch loop as u did on the method before

Comment: His switch case is missing `break` statements, and I would make the _case_ that will the difference is meaningless between else if and switch case, however, mapping them to an array would make the code more flexible.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I forgot the break, & I wasn't sure if switch will work with strings.

Comment: The print function was not copied properly. Sorry for that.

Comment: Thank you ! The break statement did it !